# Another Blogger is pointing to their site with my domain, what should I do?

Tags: domain, blogger

How do I investigate the issue of another Blogger account using my domain to point to their site?

I am using Blogger and they automatically check whether some other user is using the domain. If they find that someone else is using my domain, it provides the following error:

> Another blog or Google Site is already using this address.

I want to just kill the idle blog using my domain so that I can continue my development -- this is very frustrating.

I am unable to get the URLs fixed unless the other blog stops preserving or parking on it. When I update my A records to Google in GoDaddy, I am unable to set up the settings in Blogger due to the domain preservation, even though I own the domain.

Answer (score 1):

This would require the assistance of Google to resolve.  A search turned up articles mentioning this link: https://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?key=pZHHZdeYKeHitQbvxkvwnCg&

If Google is still monitoring that form, you may be able to enter your domain name there to have them resolve it.  If that doesn't work, you'll have to post on the Google Help site for Blogger and hope that someone from Google looks at/resolves your problem.

Most likely someone else used to own that domain name; now that you're the owner, they should be able to remove the old record to allow you to use it.

Comment: I have posted my site many times there but it won't get cleared. Yes, you are right, the last user used Google products -- and I may have even tried Google Apps but I cannot remember how to log in there and remove, frustrating.

Comment: That's one of the downsides of relying on Google's "free" products...There's generally little to no support.  If you hit a blocking issue like you did, you're probably just out of luck.  Their customers are their advertisers, not the users of the service